# How to change default save location for downloaded package with “add” command?

Tags: package, julia

I want the packages to be downloaded and saved in drive E instead of drive C. I read about `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` in [this article](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/environment-variables/#JULIA_DEPOT_PATH), however I don't know the specific steps to do, could you please take a moment to make a demonstration for me?

[image: Screenshot of REPL]

Comment: Cross post: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-change-default-save-location-for-downloaded-package-with-add-command/66998

Comment: it is me, i need what others help me

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you use Windows it is just enough to do:

```
SET JULIA_DEPOT_PATH=C:\your\path
```

Please follow this example

```
C:\Users\pszufe>SET JULIA_DEPOT_PATH=C:\Users\pszufe\mypath

C:\Users\pszufe>julia
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.7.0-beta3.0 (2021-07-07)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  release-1.7/e76c9dad42 (fork: 68 commits, 78 days)
|__/                   |

julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.7.0-beta3.0
Commit e76c9dad42 (2021-07-07 08:12 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Windows (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-12.0.0 (ORCJIT, skylake)
Environment:
  JULIA_DEPOT_PATH = C:\Users\pszufe\mypath
```

The JULIA_DEPOT_PATH can be also set as system environment variable:

[image]